# Simple MYSQL data query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Just a really simple question. In my SQL database I have a column named "friend_count" in table "users" to record all friends the logged in user has. This works with UserID numbers and I am trying to figure out how to record them all. Here's my example:

USER #29 becomes friends with USER #422

In the user database under USER #29's info in the column "friend_count" there will then be the number "422", if he then becomes friends with USER #500, it will show "422, 500" and so on... If he deletes one, that particular number is removed from the box. The script will then search these numbers through the user database to show a list of the people you are friends with.

How can I do this? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: That's no good idea. You should use a separate table where you list those friendship relations.

Comment: How would I do this ? I have no idea how to connect one table to another one?

Comment: You should read about [using MySQL Join statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: How about putting json alike documents in friend_count fields, you might need to manually delete one in php. but It won't be best practice and you better use different tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a relationship between two entities so you can create a table to store the details of that relationship.

Suppose that you have your user table with a userid column and other columns. You can then create a friends table with two columns that are both foreign keys to the user table.

```
      friends = (user, friend)
```

Thus, for each friend that user #29 gets you need to add a row into the friends table. For example:

```
    USER
    ID   NAME  ...
    29   Sam
    30   Henry
    32   Jane


    Friends
    user     friend
    29       30
    29       32
```

Sam is friends with both Jane and Henry but Jane and Henry are not friends.

Comment: So the new table would only require 2 columns? Just "Userid" and "Friend" then I connect userid to userid from the Users table??

Comment: Ah I understand, why would I need to make them foreign keys? I'm pretty new to this stuff?

Comment: At least yes. But potentially this table can have more columns that describe the relationship itself. Suppose you wanted to know the date that this friendship started for instance, you can add a column for that.

Comment: You use [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-foreign-keys.html) to enforce referential integrity. That means you cannot be friends with someone who is not a person in the user table. Suppose #29 was friends with #50 but when you look up #50 in the user table there is no such user? Foreign Keys assist with  ensuring that this does not happen.

Answer (score 3):

Any time you have a delimited list of values in a column it's *almost always* a sign that the data model is incorrect.  (Actually, I can't think of an exception to this, but I'll stick with "almost always" just to be safe.)

In this case you have two types of entities:

- User
- Friendship

A friendship, though not a physical object, is a conceptual entity in and of itself.  It connects two users and can add more information related to the friendship itself but not necessarily to the two users.

So you might have tables like this:

```
User
--------
ID
Name
etc.

Friendship
--------
ID
OriginatingUser
AcceptingUser
BecameFriendsOn
etc.
```

So `OriginatingUser` might be the user who sent the friend request, and `AcceptingUser` might be the user who accepted it.  `BecameFriendsOn` is the date it was accepted.  You'd probably want to have statuses and other dates to keep track of pending requests, denied requests, etc.  But all of this information is related to the friendship, not necessarily to the users.

The concept you're looking to understand here is called a Foreign Key.  The `OriginatingUser` and `AcceptingUser` columns are the same data type as the `ID` column on the `User` table.  You would create the `Friendship` table such that those columns are foreign keys to the `User` table, this enforces the integrity of the data so that you can't create a `Friendship` record without two valid and existing `User` records.

Then to get the list of friends, you'd join the tables in a query.  Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT
  User.Name
FROM
  Friendship
  INNER JOIN User ON Friendship.AcceptingUser = User.ID
WHERE
  Friendship.OriginatingUser = ?
```

When supplied with the ID of the originating user, this would get all of the names of users to whom that user sent a friend request.  You can further build on the query to also get users who sent this same user a friend request, and so on.  By making use of the key foreign key relationships between tables which represent different types of entities in the system, you can construct very robust queries to view that data in lots of different ways.

Comment: One case would be stuffing xml data structure into the column.  Doing that sometime makes things a bit more dynamic and easier than ALTER table.

Comment: @Zuzlx: Good example.  Though conceptually I'd argue that the XML-serialized data is itself a single "value", just one which the overlying application can deserialize into a non-primative type.  At that point it's just semantics though, you're correct in that it's still multiple pieces of data stuffed into a column.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a table "friendship" with two cols "user" and "friend", then you start adding pairs of user/friend ids

Answer (score 0):

**users table:**
id, username, whatever else

**friends table:**
relationship_id, user_id, user_friend_id

example query to get a list of IDs that belong to the users friends:

```
SELECT f.user_friend_id FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN friends f ON f.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.id = {$user_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach, assuming that if `UserA` becomes friends with `UserB` , then `UserB` also becomes friends with `UserA`.

Usually, Comma Separated Lists are not recommended, as they will become a pain when the list is very large. A simpler approach will be, make a table `friends` with columns `user_id` and `friend_id` Where user_id and friend_id are the respective UserIDs .

Now when you want to add a friend to someone's list, use the following :

`INSERT INTO users (user_id,friend_id) VALUES(UserA,UserB),(UserB,UserA)`

Now when you execute the above query, you will have 2 new rows in your `friends` table :

user_id        friend_id

UserA          UserB
UserB          UserA

When you want to get the list of a user's friends, use :

`SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id=(Your user's ID)`

This will return a row one by one, and hence will give you all the IDs of friends of a particular user.

Now when you want to delete a friend, use :

`DELETE FROM friends WHERE (user_id,friend_id) IN ((user_id,friend_id),(friend_id,user_id))`

This removes both the rows from the table, which means that the relationship between UserA and UserB is deleted, and neither of them is friend of each other.